# Can't get attribute 'ClassName' on module '__main__' from airflow

Tags: python, pickle, airflow

I am using [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) to orchestrate my data pipeline. In one of the tasks, I'm trying to load a pickled object (`RouteModel` instance) from S3:

```
def read_file_from_s3(bucket, file):
    from inference.route_model import RouteModel

    s3_loader = S3Client(bucket, None)
    buffer = s3_loader.get_file(file)

    data = pickle.loads(buffer.read())
```

which gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cyrusghazanfar/Desktop/startup-studio/pilota_project/pilota_ml/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 926, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/Users/cyrusghazanfar/Desktop/startup-studio/pilota_project/pilota_ml/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 113, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/Users/cyrusghazanfar/Desktop/startup-studio/pilota_project/pilota_ml/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 118, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/Users/cyrusghazanfar/Desktop/startup-studio/pilota_project/pilota_ml/inference/predict.py", line 43, in get_pred_for_flight
    pred_state, pred_state_prob, pred_dt = tst_pipeline.get_prediction(format_pred_od)
  File "/Users/cyrusghazanfar/Desktop/startup-studio/pilota_project/pilota_ml/inference/pipeline.py", line 174, in get_prediction
    route_model = self.rm_loader.get_model(self.rm_dict[r_key]['rm_key'])
  File "/Users/cyrusghazanfar/Desktop/startup-studio/pilota_project/pilota_ml/inference/dataloader.py", line 40, in get_model
    route_model = read_file_from_s3(self.loc, fname)
  File "/Users/cyrusghazanfar/Desktop/startup-studio/pilota_project/pilota_ml/inference/dataloader.py", line 96, in read_file_from_s3
    data = pickle.loads(buffer.read())
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'RouteModel' on <module '__main__' from '/Users/cyrusghazanfar/Desktop/startup-studio/pilota_project/pilota_ml/env/bin/airflow'>
```

When working with custom classes, the class being pickled must appear in the namespace of the process reading the pickle, which in this case is Airflow.

NOTE:

I cannot change the way I pickled the file

help please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue I needed to write my own custom unpickler where I explicitly return the custom class of the specific instance the pickle file is referring too:

```
class CustomUnpickler(pickle.Unpickler):

    def find_class(self, module, name):
        if name == 'RouteModel':
            from inference.route_model import RouteModel
            return RouteModel
        return super().find_class(module, name)

 data = CustomUnpickler(io.BytesIO(buffer.read())).load()
```